# create page title from custom post type fields

Tags: wordpress-theming, custom-post-type

I'd like to create the title of my custom type posts based on the custom fields the user enters. For example i have fields 'first name' and 'last name' and want the title created from whatever the user enters and the permalink to create the slug from it too.

I've tried this at the end of my declaring the custom type in functions.php:

```
function save_member(){
global $post;
update_post_meta($post->ID, "fname", $_POST["fname"]);
update_post_meta($post->ID, "lname", $_POST["lname"]); 
$this_post = array();   
$this_post['ID'] = $post->ID;   
$this_post['post_title'] = $_POST["fname"].' '.$_POST["lname"]; 
wp_update_post($this_post);
}
```

It just hangs if i add the last 4 lines of the code above.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are that you are initiating a loop when wp_update_post is called by firing some do_action() call within there (or related function calls).

Do this:

```
public static function repair_title( $title ){
  global $post;

  // only do this for a specific type, may want to 
  // expand this as needed
  if( "your_type" != $post->post_type ) return $title;

  $firstname        = $_POST["firstname"];
  $lastname         = $_POST["firstname"];

  $title = $firstname . " " . $lastname;

  return $title;
}

public static function repair_name( $name ){
  global $post;
  if( "your_type" != $post->post_type ) return $name;

  $firstname        = $_POST["firstname"];
  $lastname         = $_POST["firstname"];

  $name = wp_unique_post_slug(
    $firstname . " " . $lastname,
    $post->ID,
    $post->post_type,
    0
  );

  return $name;
}
```

Edit: changed this upon noting a bit of a bug in my own code (I just happened to be working on this at the moment). I was using get_post_custom() and this is fired before the post object is changed, so you need to grab your values form the $_POST posted form variables.

Cheers!